# How to create Greengrass group(aws iot)

Tags: powershell, aws-iot

I need to create Greengrass group and core in aws iot(windows).

I have referred with the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/greengrass/create-group.html

I have tried with powershell script `aws greengrass create-group \ --name ggawsgreen`

Gets error when executing above powershell script . error => aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

How to create  Greengrass group and core(aws iot) in windows powershell

Comment: So, you tried that command... and what happened? Did you get an error message? Please [edit] your question and give details.

Comment: gets error when executing above powershell script . error => aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.

Comment: OK, so your problem isn't actually to do with setting up Greengrass, it's to do with install the AWS command-line tools?

Comment: I have tried with Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer -Force command. but still getting error. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/greengrass/create-group.html

Comment: @IMSoP Can you help me

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part of the problem. Forget about Greengrass for now; your current task is to install the AWS command-line tools, the official instructions for which are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html I know nothing about that "Install-Module" command; wherever you found it may have more instructions that you missed, or it may be completely the wrong command. Until you can run `aws --version` and `aws help` successfully, there is no point trying to run `aws greengrass anything`.

Answer (score 0):

the error appears because you haven't installed the `AWS Command Line Interface` or `aws cli` for short.

Or ´aws cli´ is not in your `path`.

[download here](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)